# Expo BackgroundFetch not working on android when app is terminated

Tags: background, fetch, expo, background-fetch

The task gets registered it also works.When in recent apps it works.When gets deleted it stops working!

Expo CLI 3.11.3 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10
Binaries:
Yarn: 1.21.0 - C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
npm: 6.9.0 - E:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version 3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203

SDK version : 36.0.0
Standalone app on android 7

Just to confirm I was right I went into my apps background in my setting in my phone,I can see the app is in background progress.As soon as I remove it from recent apps it gets gone from the background progress too.So everything is as I described and no doubts about it.I also have used:

```
stopOnTerminate: false,
```

But it doesn’t do anything.

Here’s a function that does register the tasks and everything:

```
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

export async function registerFetchTask(taskName, jobCallback, interval) {
    TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, jobCallback);

    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    switch (status) {
        case BackgroundFetch.Status.Restricted:
        case BackgroundFetch.Status.Denied:
            console.log("Background execution is disabled");
            return;

        default: {
            console.log("Background execution allowed");

            let tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
            if (tasks.find(f => f.taskName === taskName) == null) {
                console.log("Registering task");
                await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName,{
                    minimumInterval: 60,
                    stopOnTerminate: false,
                    startOnBoot: true,
                });

                tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
                console.log("Registered tasks", tasks);
            } else {
                console.log(`Task ${taskName} already registered, skipping`);
            }

            console.log("Setting interval to", interval);
            await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(interval);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside app.js I call:

```
registerFetchTask('wow',()=>{
fetchServer('/test',{});
console.log('WOWWW HIIIIIIIII YGNNNNNN');
},5);
```

The fetchServer will add things to my database on my laptop.So I can see if the app is running the task I’m getting new rows in the database.